# Conditional exit transition between screens using onGenerateRoute

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm setting my routes and transition animations through `onGenerateRoute` which is working great except I want differents transition animations depending on a condition (on choosen path for example) :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        if (settings.name == '/') {
          return PageRouteBuilder<dynamic>(
            pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
                    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) =>
                Page1(),
            transitionsBuilder: (
              BuildContext context,
              Animation<double> animation,
              Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
              Widget child,
            ) {
              return SlideTransition(
                position: Tween<Offset>(
                  begin: Offset.zero,
                  end: const Offset(-1.0, 0.0),
                ).animate(secondaryAnimation), // Here I want to have differents transitions
                child: child,
              );
            },
          );
        } else if (settings.name == '/second') {
          return PageRouteBuilder<dynamic>(
            pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
                    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) =>
                Page2(),
            transitionsBuilder: (
              BuildContext context,
              Animation<double> animation,
              Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
              Widget child,
            ) {
              return SlideTransition(
                  position: Tween<Offset>(
                          begin: const Offset(1.0, 0.0), end: Offset.zero)
                      .animate(animation),
                  child: SlideTransition(
                    position: Tween<Offset>(
                      begin: Offset.zero,
                      end: const Offset(0.0, 1.0),
                    ).animate(secondaryAnimation),
                    child: child,
                  ));
            },
          );
        } else if (settings.name == '/third') {
          return PageRouteBuilder<dynamic>(
            pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
                    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) =>
                Page3(),
            transitionsBuilder: (
              BuildContext context,
              Animation<double> animation,
              Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
              Widget child,
            ) {
              return SlideTransition(
                  position: Tween<Offset>(
                          begin: const Offset(0.0, 1.0), end: Offset.zero)
                      .animate(animation),
                  child: SlideTransition(
                    position: Tween<Offset>(
                      begin: Offset.zero,
                      end: const Offset(0.0, 1.0),
                    ).animate(secondaryAnimation),
                    child: child,
                  ));
            },
          );
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Page 1"), backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second'),
              child: Text("Go to Page 2 with exit transition slide left"),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/third'),
              child: Text("Go to Page 3 with transition slide top"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Page 2"), backgroundColor: Colors.green),
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              child: Text("Go back to page 1"))),
    );
  }
}

class Page3 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Page 3"), backgroundColor: Colors.yellow),
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
      body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              child: Text("Go back to page 1"))),
    );
  }
}
```

[See codePen here](https://codepen.io/Fluckysan/pen/mdPpMgb)

As the exit transition animation (via `secondaryAnimation`) is set before the screen is displayed, I can't change the animation dynamically depending on the button clicked. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: You can pass a argument through the navigator, accept it in the PageRouteBuilder, then change the transition based on a switch statement.

Comment: @ScottGodfrey I'm speaking about the exit transition animation which is set by the secondaryAnimation during the route call (so and the beggining of the leaving screen creation), there is no way to know which button will be clicked at this moment

Comment: You can't change the actual transition, but you can change the how it animates.  Before returning the SlideTransition, you can change the animation and secondaryAnimation.  secondaryAnimation = //new animation.

Comment: Yes I know, the question is how can I have 2 different exit animations depending on the button clicked ? Please have a look at the codePen to try it out

Comment: Posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
   (RouteSettings settings) {
      final transition = settings.arguments as String;
      if (settings.name == '/') {
      return PageRouteBuilder<dynamic>(
        pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
                Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) =>
            Page1(),
        transitionsBuilder: (
          BuildContext context,
          Animation<double> animation,
          Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
          Widget child,
        ) {
           switch (transition) {
             case 'firstTransition':
               secondaryAnimation = //first animation 
             break;
             case 'secondTransition':
               secondaryAnimation = //second animation
             break;
           }

          return SlideTransition(
            position: Tween<Offset>(
              begin: Offset.zero,
              end: const Offset(-1.0, 0.0),
            ).animate(secondaryAnimation), // Here I want to have differents transitions
            child: child,
          );
        },
      );
```

Comment: Thx for the answer but when I'll click on one of the "Go to Page 2" or "Go to Page 3", the router won't go on the settings.name == '/' part anymore so the secondaryAnimation (exit animation for Page 1) won't change. You see ?

Comment: You'll have to do do the switch on each page that you want to modify the secondaryAnimation.  The only way to make it cleaner is to setup a BasePageRoute  that extends PageRouteBuilder.  After that, you can assign concrete implementations to the base.